# Load pdf file to jar already built

Tags: java, maven, pdf, jar

I'm trying to get some specific data from a pdf and save it in a database. The idea is that in my program when you press a button, with selenium, the program downloads the pdf and uploads it to the jar in order to read it.

I tried many libraries to read pdfs but all seems to be stuck in the same place: when I try to load the pdf.

If I compile the program in IntelliJ it works perfect, the problem is when I compile it to .jar. It gets stuck when loading and does not show an error. Tried everything I could but nothing works.

Heres how my code looks right now:

```
              try {

                    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("out/artifacts/WAsNEWWINDOWS_jar/bills/facturaClaro.pdf");
                    System.out.println("This PDF has "+reader.getNumberOfPages()+" pages.");
                    String page = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 2);
                    System.out.println("Page Content:\n\n"+page+"\n\n");
                    System.out.println("Is this document tampered: "+reader.isTampered());
                    System.out.println("Is this document encrypted: "+reader.isEncrypted());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

The coding like this works perfect in IntelliJ, and when I compile it to .jar I change the location of the file like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("bills/facturaClaro.pdf");
```

Any contribution can help me. Thank you so much!

EDIT: I would like to clarify that for now I'm not downloading the pdf, I just copy the pdf file in the same directory as the .jar.

UPDATE: apparently it was throwing an exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader
    at BillReader.readClaro(BillReader.java:195)
    at WebScrapper.startBillReaderClaro(WebScrapper.java:467)
    at Controller$20.call(Controller.java:4182)
    at Controller$20.call(Controller.java:4179)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

I search for a solution but nothing works. Please help me! Thank you

EDIT: my pom.xml looks like this btw, no repetition of dependencies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>WAs</groupId>
    <artifactId>seleWA</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.8.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appName>SimManager</appName>
                    <vendor>YourCompany</vendor>
                    <mainClass>SimManager</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>sample.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java/excel</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.0</version>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.16</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox-app</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.liferay.document.library.service</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.simplejavamail</groupId>
            <artifactId>simple-java-mail</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>

            <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.Lamba92</groupId>
            <artifactId>kresourceloader</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lynden</groupId>
            <artifactId>GMapsFX</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15</artifactId>
            <version>1.44</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
            <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.13</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

</project>
```

[project structure libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elQYG.png)
[libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZMEu.png)

Comment: The class not found in your jar is part of the itextpdf dependency. So you have it in your dependencies, it merely is not added by your result jar. Have you checked whether any of your other dependencies is added? I don't know intellij details but for maven the assembly plugin should be associated with a build phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it !. I just analyzed the .jar with the command:

```
jar tvf WAsNEWWINDOWS.jar
```

and I realize that indeed, the necessary class was not there. As I had already seen the libraries in the project structure in IntelliJ, I looked at the artifacts extracted, and I could see that iText was not there, so I added it as "extracted directory" and searched where the iText .jar was and thats it! . Compile the jar again and there wasn't any error and it works perfect !. I leave an image where you need to add the .jar:

[intellij extract directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnIRh.png)

Answer (score 0):

That exception looks like you dont have the correct dependency in your maven repository. Try to see if both `PdfReader` functions have the same dependency. Like you say, you tried so much librarys, maybe two of them have the same name function and you are mixed them in some way.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your reply! I updated my question with my pom.xml. With two function what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Inside this dependency:
`<dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.13</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>`
Do you ve the package of `com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader` ?

Comment: How do I check if iI have it? I'm using intellij and it's supposed to download everything automatically. I updated my question with a pic of what I found in my libraries in project structure.

Comment: looks you resolve it =)
my advice next time you have a similar error is to use a decompiler with the libary jar to search a posible missing dependency
[Link to my favourite decompiler](http://java-decompiler.github.io/)